# Select rows from a table based on max value in different table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, max

I'm looking for a MySQL query to extract values like in the following example:

```
TABLE1:
 ID     name   
 25     ab       
 24     abc      
 23     abcd       
 22     abcde      
 21     abcdef 


 TABLE2:
 ID     ID_TABLE1   total       
 1      25          0
 2      25          1
 3      25          2
 4      25          3
 5      23          1
 6      22          0
 7      22          1
 8      21          0
 9      21          2
 10     24          10
 11     24          7
```

I want to return all `TABLE1` rows where max value of `total` column (in `TABLE2`) is < 3.
 So the results should be:

```
 ID     name   
 23     abcd       
 22     abcde      
 21     abcdef
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM TABLE1 t1
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT MAX( total ) AS max_total, ID_TABLE1
        FROM TABLE2
        GROUP BY total, ID_TABLE1
) t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID_TABLE1
WHERE t2.max_total < 3
```

but it's not the result I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner query groups the results by `id_table` **and by total**. Since the maximum of `total` per `total` is the value itself, it makes the inner query somewhat meaningless. Just remove the `total` from the `group by` clause and you should be OK:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM TABLE1 t1
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT   MAX( total ) AS max_total, ID_TABLE1
        FROM     TABLE2
        GROUP BY ID_TABLE1
) t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID_TABLE1
WHERE t2.max_total < 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.name
FROM TABLE1 t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID_TABLE1, MAX(total) AS max_total 
            FROM TABLE2 
            GROUP BY ID_TABLE1 
          ) t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID_TABLE1 
WHERE t2.max_total < 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT t1.*
FROM TABLE1 t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT   MAX( total ) AS max_total, ID_TABLE1
    FROM     TABLE2
    GROUP BY ID_TABLE1
    having t2.max_total < 3
  ) t2
 ON t1.ID = t2.ID_TABLE1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do using `left join` without using any subquery and group by clauses.

```
select t1.* from table1 t1
join table2 t2
on t1.id = t2.id_table1
left join table2 t3 on
t2.id_table1 = t3.id_table1
and t2.total < t3.total
where t3.id is null
and t2.total < 3
```

Another way is

```
select t1.* from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id_table1
where not exists(
  select 1 from table2 t3
  where t2.id_table1 = t3.id_table1
  and t2.total < t3.total
)
and t2.total < 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT t1.*

FROM TABLE1 t1

INNER JOIN (

```
    SELECT MAX( total ) AS max_total, ID_TABLE1
    FROM TABLE2
     where total > 3  GROUP BY total, ID_TABLE1
```

) t2
ON t1.ID != t2.ID_TABLE1

Answer (score 0):

There's a simpler way without using `GROUP` or `MAX`:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT id_table1 FROM table2 WHERE total >= 3
);
```

The subquery selects all rows in `table2` that have a total >= 3. Then we select those rows from `table1` that are not in the subquery result.